# Jquery to Format 0.00 to 00.00 using .Tofixed() function or Else

Tags: jquery, format

I need to format float value from 0.00 to 00.00.
currently i use .toFixed function but this function return me 0.00 but i want to 00.00. Friends help me for this .

Thanks  in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the output of `toFixed` and, if the whole number part is just one digit, add a `0` in front of it. There are about a dozen ways to do that. Here's one using a regular expression:

```js
var num = 1.23;
var str = num.toFixed(2).replace(/^\d\./, '0$&');
document.body.innerHTML = str;
```

The regular expression matches a single digit (`\d`) at start of string (`^`) followed by a dot (`\.`; escaped because otherwise dots are special). If found, it replaces it with the string that it found (`$&`) with a `0` in front of it.

Another way is `split` and `join`:

```js
var num = 1.23;
var parts = num.toFixed(2).split('.');
if (parts[0].length == 1) {
    parts[0] = "0" + parts[0];
}
var str = parts.join(".");
document.body.innerHTML = str;
```

Another way is `indexOf` and `substring`:

```js
var num = 1.23;
var str = num.toFixed(2);
if (str.indexOf(".") === 1) {
    str = "0" + str.charAt(0) + str.substring(1);
}
document.body.innerHTML = str;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, Code is run perfectly for me. Thanks a lot again for such a great support.